# calling fclose on a memstream FILE causes segmentation fualt

Tags: c, fclose

I have an interface that only prints strings to a file and Im working on a embedded system so opening a file is not an option 
I created a virtual file in a memory using `open_memstream` , and after using the file and parsing the string the program fails on `fclose` causing a segmentation fault 
here's the code :

```
/*
 * Creating a temp file in memory
 */
FILE * mem_stream;
char * mem_buf;
size_t mem_len;
mem_stream = open_memstream(mem_buf,&mem_len);

XMLDoc_print(doc, mem_stream, NULL, NULL, 0, 0 ,0);
XMLDoc_free(doc);

/*
 * Reading the temp file
 */

fseek(mem_stream,0,SEEK_END);
long file_size = ftell(mem_stream);
rewind(mem_stream);
char * contents = malloc( (file_size+1) * sizeof(char) );
fread(contents, sizeof(char), file_size, mem_stream);
/*
 * closing the file
 */
fclose(mem_stream);
contents[file_size] = 0;


printf("\n THE RESULT XML IS : %s \n" , contents);
```

If i comment the `fclose(mem_stream);` line the program works fine , is this an option ? if not how can i fix this.

Comment: shouldn't `open_memstream()` functions first parameter be `char **`.?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Yes I was wondering how that went through for OP

Comment: I doubled checked the `char **bufp` parameter for `open_memstream()` it goes fine with either `char*` or `char**`.I guess since it just needs an char pointer and I don't use it anyways

Comment: `it goes fine with either char* or char**` do you have idea why they'd need a `char **`, not a `char*`? Hint: possible `realloc()`

Comment: on the tutorial page here http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open_memstream.html they've used `char *` themselves so actually no

Comment: The error is when you close the stream because that is when the two pointers passed are written to.

Comment: @AlirezaSoori Yes, but they are passing the *address of* that `char *` to `open_memstream`. If you don't understand the difference between `char *` and `char **` you should do some reading about pointers before trying to use them.

Answer (score 1):

`mem_stream = open_memstream(mem_buf,&mem_len);`  this line should be like this :
`mem_stream = open_memstream(&mem_buf,&mem_len);` 
as said in the function's documentation

> /* Open a stream that writes into a malloc'd buffer that is expanded as
>      necessary.  *BUFLOC and *SIZELOC are updated with the buffer's location
>      and the number of characters written on fflush or fclose.  */

```
extern FILE *open_memstream (char **__bufloc, size_t *__sizeloc) __THROW __wur;
```

the `char ** __bufloc` is an address to a char * buffer.